# How to calculate the summary of input current in finite element model?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current

I have a finite element model of homogeneous conductor in electricity with stable voltages setting. For simplicity, the conductor is in 2d dimension and a round shape. The boundary is insulated. I set some vertices with pre-defined potentials.(The red vertices are in 1 voltage and blue vertices in zero). [image: mesh figure]

My problem is how to calculate the total input and output current intensity of this model? I could build the stiff matrix to calculate the potential at every vertex. Then I could get the electric field in each triangle mesh with differential. But next how to calculate the total input current in the red or blue vertices (or on the edge cover them) ?
Mainly, I have two puzzles in this problem.

1. I had two way to calculate the norm of the total current. One is to calculate the total x and y dimensional current among red/blue vertices. Then calculate the norm of them. The second way is to calculate the norm of x and y dimensional current at every vertices or edges, then summarize the "norms" together. Which way is right? Which step should be done firstly, the norm or the sum?
2. Should the total input and output current be same? Intuition, they should be same. But in my calculation, they seems not. So I doubt this assumption.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I am very confused in this problem for several days. Thank you.